# Log4net json does not create output any messages

Tags: c#, json, windows-services, log4net

So I have a windows service application that was using log4net and outputting messages in text format so far. Due to a certain change I now have to output the messages in json format so I found this convenient extension: https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net.Ext.Json/

I followed the instructions here https://gitlab.com/BrightOpen/log4net.Ext.Json#json-stuff and now have added the appender in the dedicated config file like so:

```
<appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="MessageTracker.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
  <maximumFileSize value="20MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="MessageTracker.json" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="dd-MM-yyyy" />
  <PreserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maximumFileSize value="20MB" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
  <dateTimeStrategy type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender+UniversalDateTime" />


  <layout type="log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json">
    <decorator type="log4net.Layout.Decorators.StandardTypesDecorator, log4net.Ext.Json" />
    <member value="date:date" />
    <member value="level:level" />
    <member value="logger:logger" />
    <member value="message:messageObject" />
    <member value="exception:exception" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
  <appender-ref ref="console" />
  <appender-ref ref="file" />
</root>
```

And here is my AsemblyInfo.cs referencing that config file:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4Net.config", Watch = true)]
```

When I debug the service on my local machine, it all works fine and I can see both files outputing in my debug folder. When I try installing the service on a remote machine however, I get an error:

```
log4net:ERROR Failed to find type [log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json]
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'log4net, Version=2.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT
: 0x80131040)
File name: 'log4net, Version=2.0.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a'
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(Assembly relativeAssembly, String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Util.SystemInfo.GetTypeFromString(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.XmlHierarchyConfigurator.CreateObjectFromXml(XmlElement element, Type defaultTargetType, Type typeConstraint)
```

But that doesn't help me much because I can see all necessary DLLs (log4net.dll and log4net.Ext.Json.dll) next to my executable that I am installing.

Since the service actually does install successfully, I can run and and see logs in my old text file but the json file only gets created while staying completely blank with 0kb of space.

I am developing this service in .NET framework 4.6.1.

I feel like I am missing a part in the config file, any help would be appretiated.

Comment: I believe your target machine may be missing a required runtime. Looking at the nuget package, it says it requires .NetFrame 4.5.2. Can you check if that's installed and if not, try installing it?

Comment: I just tried downloading and installing but the installer says that 4.5.2 or later version currently exists.

Comment: Could it be possiblely be turned off? If you go to control panel -> programs -> turn windows features on or off -> make sure .Net 4.8 is checked. You might also be able to use 3.5 ( I could be wrong on that though)

Comment: HI @Rye, all the features in .NET framework 3.5 and 4.6 are installed, there is nothing else to tick.

Comment: I see. How about the log4net version types? Can you compare your version of log4net with the version of log4net that exists in your services bin folder? If one of the projects in the solution references a different version of log4net (or one of it's dependencies) it might cause that error.

Comment: Hey @Rye, I checked that as well, both log4net.dll and log4net.Ext.Json.dll display 2.0.12.0 and 2.0.9.1 respectively in both the visual studio and in the bin folder properties.